# jQuery: Add Class to AJAX-loaded Pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

```
$(".paginate li").click(function(){
    $(this).attr('class','current');    
    $("#ajax_results").load("test.php?page=" + $(this).attr('rel')).fadeIn();
});
```

The above code is for a pagination script.  When the user clicks the pagination <li> the AJAX script fires off a request based on the rel value.  The issue I am having is with:

```
$(this).attr('class','current');
```

It applies for a brief second and then vanishes.  Ideally it would apply a class of 'current' to the clicked <li> and remain.  I'm not sure why it is being removed immediately after being applied.

Comment: If you comment out the 2nd line and use `$(this).addClass('current');` does that work? Now try uncomment the 2nd line, does that work still? Trial and error.

Comment: is `this` a descendant of `#ajax_results`?

Comment: @Martin - My apologies I should have specified that I had already tried the addClass() function to no avail.  Both attr() and addClass() behave identically in this situation; the highlight appears and is removed immediately.

Comment: @Kevin It is a descendant of `$(".paginate li").click(function(){` so it would be 'the LI of class paginate that was clicked'

Comment: Right, but my question was is that in any way a descendant of `#ajax_results`. It being a descendant of `.paginate li` doesn't answer that, it could be both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own problem and thought I would post the solution.  After reviewing the code it became obvious that the issue with adding the class is that `$(this)` is no longer defined once the AJAX call is made.  There may be a more elegant workaround but what I've done is below:

```
$(".paginate li").click(function(){
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');

    $("#ajax_results").load("/ajax.php?id=" + $(this).attr('rel'), function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            $("li[rel="+rel+"]").addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

I declare `rel` as the value of `$(this).attr('rel')` and then on success pass along the `addClass()` function to the relevant item.  Works perfectly.